# Redirect Old url with new url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect

> I am redeveloping a site in codeigniter .  so there are some page have
>   static information but i have change the url . now i want that if user
>   type the old url it should automatically redirect to new url here is
>   examle OLD URL  1) 
>   http://example.com/international/university-english-access-course
>
> new url
>
> 1) http://example.com/website/page/english-access
>
> i am using codeigniter. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

in your application/config/routes.php file add this line

```
$config['website/page/english-access'] = 'international/university-english-access-course';
```

to learn more about url routing check this link

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: it should be other way round `$config['international/university-english-access-course'] = 'website/page/english-access';`